# Managing Several Xamarin Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, version-control, bitbucket

I have built a template for android/iOS applications using Xamarin with Visual Studio on my Mac. That template is used to create similar applications for different clients and publish them on the App Store/Google Play market. The only difference between the applications is usually a splash screen, color scheme and a main app icon. I am concerned with the version control of these projects.

For example I have that template stored on a private bitbucket repository and use it every time I want to create another application. Currently I have 6 published applications (each also stored in different branches of that repo).

What if I would make changes to the main template, how is it possible to apply the changes to all the projects without going through each one of them and apply the changes to the main part of the project one by one? Wouldn't pulling the main repo change all the app-specific materials inside each project?

Comment: this is called "white labeling".  There are numerous posts and articles about how to do it.

Comment: thank you! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @denistepp Hi, if have solved it later, remember to share the solution here when you have time. It will be helpful for other people who have the same problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several solutions to this:

1. Version Control tools, such as git to manage one (common) project and put the others in separate branches. This is a popular method, but time consuming if you have many projects.
2. By using different configurations in visual studio. Each configuration will respond to specific application that you will be implementing. The only downside I have found so far is that Apple rejects applications that were built this way. I haven't checked that myself, can't be saying for sure.

Anyways, the most helpful links for me were:

- https://www.xamboy.com/2019/05/01/multiple-application-installation-based-on-the-solution-configuration/
- https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/#comments
- https://github.com/andrius-k/Whitelabeled.Xamarin
- https://mobilebuildtools.com